# Is there an efficient method to store large DAGs?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, partial-order

I have a DAG representing strict partial order where each node is an assignment of variables $V$ to their values $v$. Each arc $(u,w)$ represents a change in one variable value such that $u\succ w$.

So if I have $n$ binary variables, I will end up with $2^n$ nodes which is exponential to the size of variables $n$. is there any method to store such DAG efficiently?

Comment: Why store anything? You can compute if there is an edge  $(u,w)$ by using the same function that makes the edge that go between $u$ and $w$.

Comment: @PratikDeoghare actually i'm trying to solve dominance task: given two nodes $n_1$ and $n_2$ which one is better $n_1\succ n_2$ or $n_2\succ n_1$. I can partially search the graph starting from $n_1$ for example. But this is hard problem in general. so I was looking for a method to index all the nodes and make it easier to answer the dominance task.

Comment: @Seteropere I agree with Pratik. I did not understand what you mean by ".. which one is better ..". If I understand correctly, either $n_1 \prec n_2$ or $n_2 \prec n_1$ or neither dominates each other. You can check this by a linear traversal of the vectors of both $n_1$ and $n_2$. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Paresh You got it. would you please elaborate more on *linear traversal of the vectors of both *. You mean checking outgoing paths from both $n_1$ and $n_2$ ?

Comment: @Seteropere Say each point is a vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ of $m$ values (of any type). Say, you want to compare $n_1$ and $n_2$ having vectors $\overrightarrow{v_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{v_2}$ respectively. Then, for each of the $m$ values in $\overrightarrow{v_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{v_2}$, compare which dominates/is greater than the other. If all values of $\overrightarrow{v_1}$ dominate the corresponding values of $\overrightarrow{v_2}$, then $n_1$ dominates $n_2$, and vice-versa. If some values dominate, and some are dominated, then neither $n_1$ nor $n_2$ dominate each other.

Answer (score 2):

Try constructing a reduced ordered binary decision diagram (ROBDD) as described [here](http://www.configit.com/fileadmin/Configit/Documents/bdd-eap.pdf). 
The reducing algorithm removes redundant nodes, and reuses equal subtrees in the decision tree, such that every node is unique.
The memory complexity of a ROBDD is $\mathcal O({2^n \over n})$ as proved [here](http://tkuir.lib.tku.edu.tw:8080/dspace/bitstream/987654321/21041/1/0018-9340_+41%286%29p661-664.pdf).

Comment: Thank Simon. does it preserve the arcs? i.e. the reduced diagram will have same set of arcs as the original?

Comment: Redundant arcs will be removed, i.e if the result of assigning 0 leads to an equal node as assigning 1. Any other arc is preserved.